# Qual melhor abordagem no docker quanto a containers como apache, nginx, mariadb, etc

Tags: docker

Sou novo no mundo docker e estou com algumas dúvidas a respeito do conceito do docker em produção.

Sei que uma das grandes vantagens do docker é ter o mesmo ambiente que temos em desenvolvimento na produção para que evite aqueles problemas clássicos de que na minha máquina ta rodando, mas no servidor não.

Então vejo neste caso que quando crio minha aplicação posso configurar um docker-compose.yml com as imagens necessárias para o meu ambiente. Como por exemplo apache, php5.6, mariadb e fazer um docker-compose up para ter o ambiente necessário. E da mesma forma quando outra pessoa da minha equipe pegar o projeto irá apenas fazer um docker-compose up e terá todo o necessário também sem ter q instalar e configurar nada na maquina dele.

Aí então se eu quiser mandar isso pra produção faria neste caso a mesma coisa, correto? E se outro projeto já utiliza o php7 e o postgresql então no docker-compose.yml colocarei o php7 no lugar do 6 e o postgresql no lugar do mariadb

Então é agora que vem minha dúvida.

Configurei um cluster docker e tenho visto que a abordagem é criar serviços para as imagens. Um serviço pro apache, um pro mariadb, um pro postgre e assim por diante.

Então neste caso como fica a configuração do meu docker-compose.yml? E eu terei q previamente criar serviços para cada coisa que uma nova aplicação irá necessitar? Isso não foge um pouco da facilidade do ambiente? Até porque uma aplicação pode precisar de um determinado detalhe em uma imagem q outro não precise.

Como eu disse, sou novo no mundo docker. Gostaria de conselhos para evitar de montar um ambiente de forma errada e ter q mudar tudo no futuro.

Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem sua dúvida, por isso acho melhor irmos ao básico para que você possa reformulá-la. 

O Docker, aproveita de inovações do kernel do Linux: Namespaces, cgroups, SELinux e UnionFS para poder compartilhar sistemas completos, chamados de contêineres, para executar tarefas distintas com o intúito de criar isolamento entre os sistemas, deste modo, não instala qualquer aplicação diretamente no hospedeiro, tampouco está em uma máquina virtual.

Comment: Imagem é a definição inicial do ambiente desse determinado serviço. 

Por conceito, cada conteiner executa um serviço isolado. Serviço é um processo que provê um determinado recurso. Não é indicado que tenhamos processos diferentes em background num mesmo serviço, por exemplo, se o conteiner é do apache não é seguro que ele execute um outro processo como um cron ou um mariadb. Isso ocorre pois cada imagem define um único entrypoint (processo que executará). Quando esse processo termina ou morre, o conteiner morre junto com ele.

Comment: O docker-compose é um comando do docker que lê uma descrição de serviços em yml e facilita sua orquestração e gerenciamento. É capaz por exemplo de criar elasticidade ao serviço, criando novos conteiner quando necessários.

Cluster docker é um conjunto de hospedeiros controlados de forma sincronizada.

Comment: Antes de avançar para "docker service" sugiro à você começar devagar até você adquirir proeficiência para trabalhar com isto. Comece com "docker run" rodando imagens isoladas ainda que uma imagem possa precisar da outra. Assim depois de um tempo, você vai entender como melhor utilizar o docker-compose. É uma questão de amadurecimento na tecnologia.

Comment: obrigado a todos pelas respostas